# Is there a programmatic way to tell if an Apex class is batchable?

Tags: apex, batch, metadata-api

Is there a programmatic way to determine which Apex classes in my Org are batchable (i.e. implement a batch interface)? I have looked at the Metadata API but it does not seem to have any method for this. Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell if a class implements a specific interface by using *instanceof*. For example, given the following class:

```
global class ProcessAccounts implements Database.Batchable<Account> {
    ...
}
```

You can depend on the following:

```
System.assert(((object)new ProcessAccounts()) instanceof Database.batchable<Account>);
System.assert(((object)new ProcessAccounts()) instanceof Database.batchable<subject>);
// The following is a bug?
System.assert(((object)new ProcessAccounts()) instanceof database.batchable<string>);
```

Basically, the point here is that as long as the account can be *cast* into the appropriate interface, it is considered an instance of that interface; this method will tell you if the class is indeed batchable and therefore able to be scheduled with schedulebatch or executed with executebatch.

For now, it doesn't matter what *parameter* you use for the interface, it will return true if, and only if, the class implements database.batchable in some context. This should get you a full list of classes:

```
set<system.type> batchables = new set<system.type>();
for(apexclass c:[select name from apexclass]) {
    try {
        system.type t = system.type.forname(c.name);
        if(t != null && t.newinstance() instanceof database.batchable<sobject>) {
            batchables.add(t);
        }
    } catch(exception e) { }
}
system.debug(batchables);
```

With one caveat: it does not support batchable (or really, any) classes that do not have a default constructor. Make sure that your classes have a default constructor, and this code will work just fine.

Comment: How can he use this to check all classes in his org though?  This seems to only work on a one by one case basis.

Comment: @drakored You're right. I'll update.

Comment: @drakored That better?

Comment: I've been looking for something similar and was planning to use Matt's concept too so your idea is intriguing since it is much cleaner.  I ran this against an org with 14MB+ of Apex code, no dice.  Won't even execute.  Just hangs on the anon exec screen.

Comment: Keeping in mind that I can iterate this code base in less than 2 minutes by cycling all apexclass and using containsIgnoreCase on the body field (for finding bits in the code).  This seems to be lacking a little.

Comment: @drakored Maybe there's something else going on? This runs fine in my dev org, but I only have ~1mb of code. Maybe it gets tripped up on namespaces or something. I'll have to investigate, since I'm intrigued by this.

Comment: Ran for 5-7 minutes, failed because of something in one of the constructors.  Nice solution, but no good for large orgs, or orgs calling ApexPages.addMessage/s in the constructor apparently (the exception I received was: System.Exception: ApexPages.addMessage can only be called from a Visualforce page).

+1 for the nice solution, but it has some limits that make it a little unusable in certain cases like ours unfortunately.

Comment: Seems like the correct answer is a balance between Matt's and sfdcfox's answers depending on your org circumstances.

Comment: Wonder what was the Matt's answer?
I think you should add to this answer workaround for namespace classes like

for(apexclass c:[select Name, NamespacePrefix from apexclass]) {
    try {
        system.type t = system.type.forname(c.NamespacePrefix == null || c.NamespacePrefix == '' ? c.name : c.NamespacePrefix + '.' + c.Name);
        if(t != null && t.newinstance() instanceof database.batchable<sobject>) {
            batchables.add(t);
        }
    } catch(exception e) { }
}

and probably some other workaround for other cases like nondefault constructors.

Comment: LaceySnr == Matt his solution doesn't fit inside the org

Comment: Thanks LaceySnr, sfdcfox, drakored - Looks like there is no elegant way of doing this, and the most certain answer appears to be @drakored's suggestion on iterating through the apexclass and using containsIgnoreCase to determine which classes have implemented the batchable interface. Thanks for all the suggestions. It was very helpful for me to learn from the experts here :-)

Comment: I have a code snippet I can share that I use in exec anon.  The draw back to using containsIgnoreCase is that is has no recognition of the actual pattern of the class.  If someone were to previously use the batchable interface, then comment just that part of the line out, it'd detect it as a proper use.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way to get this. Perhaps you could just search the body of the class that you get from the Metadata API, or even pull it out in Apex by querying `ApexClass` and searching the body there?

The Tooling API's `ApexClass` object has a `SymbolTable` member which in turn has a member called `interfaces` which includes the information you're after. Maybe switching to that API would be the best approach? [See the docs on `SymbolTable` here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/index.htm).

Comment: Just use InstanceOf.

Comment: Heh... totally overlooked that.